# Reconciling discussion of conformality in Rudin and Conway

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm preparing for my qualifying exam in complex analysis, and I'm trying to get a better handle on conformality. I have read the discussions of conformality in both Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" and Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable I." The two authors treat the subject somewhat differently. I think I follow the arguments that Rudin gives, but I'm still trying reconcile them with a statement that Conway makes (without proof).

Let's assume from now on that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open and connected, and that we have $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ with following property: for each $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, there exists some $r_{z_0} > 0$ where $f(z) \neq f(z_0)$ on $D_{r_{z_0}}(z_0) \setminus \{z_0\}.$ That is, $f$ is different from $f(z_0)$ on the punctured disk of radius $r_{z_0}$ centered at $z_0$.

For this type of map $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, Conway says that $f$ is *angle preserving* at $z_0$ iff

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{f(r + e^{i\theta}) - f(z_0)}{
|f(z_0 + re^{i\theta}) -f(z_0)|}$$

exists and is independent of $\theta$.

Furthermore, in an earlier chapter, Conway explains what the *differential* of a function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is. Actually, for this definition, we need to break up $f = u + iv$ into its real and imaginary parts, and think of $f$ as a map from $\Omega$, an open subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$, into $\mathbb{R^2}$. So we're thinking $f: (x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y), v(x,y)).$ The differential of $f$ is a a linear transformation $A : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that, for each point $z_0 = (x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$, we have

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|f((x_0, y_0) + (x,y)) - f(x_0,y_0) + A(x,y)|}{|(x,y)|} = 0.$$

With these definitions in hand, Conway goes on to state (and prove) theorem 14.2. The theorem is an if and only if statement, but the direction I'm concerned with says:

If $f$ preserves angles at $z_0$, and the differential exists and is different from $0$ at $z_0$, then $f'(z_0)$ exists and is different from zero.

The proof is not too tough, and I'm pretty sure I understand all the details. However, the issue I am having is when I go over and read Conway's discussion of conformality. Unfortunately, Conway does not have a formal definition of conformality/angle preservation like Rudin. He just gives an informal discussion using smooth paths. However, Conway does state the following (just after his theorem 3.4):

If $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is angle preserving and has $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{|f(z) - f(z_0)|}{|z-z_0|}$ existing for each $z_0 \in \Omega$, then each $f'(z_0)$ exists and is not $0$.

So, in the end, my question is this: assuming that Conway's "formal" definition of angle preservation is the same as Rudin's, how do we prove Conway's statement. I like what Conway says so much more than Rudin's differential messiness! Are these two statements very obviously equivalent and I'm just missing something?

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should all boil down to saying the derivative (as a linear map $A$) is conformal. In dimension 2, this means $A$ is a nonzero scalar multiple of a rotation, which of course characterizes multiplication by a nonzero complex number. Preserving angles between differentiable curves is then a consequence of the chain rule.